# How to get access to html element content (text, other components, Images) in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to use an editable div tag and after editing I am trying to access its content using angular 2 syntax:

`<div contenteditable="true" >
  {{sentence}}
</div>`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with content?  Do you need it to be available in js code?  If it were regular input, would [ngModel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html) work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `innherHTML` property of the div to find out the content of the `div` like so:

```
<div contenteditable="true" (blur)="contentChanged($event.currentTarget.innerHTML)">
    {{sentence}}
</div>
```

## [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/OMQjikcpsZy76Kf1n97r)